# Ansible URI module passing integer from variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I set a variable from a previous play that collects a value (integer), then call it in the following task using the uri module to pass it via API. But I always get a 422 error back saying "Value should be integer".

```
- name: Deploy Staging Blueprint
local_action:
  module: uri
  url: "https://{{ server_address }}/api/application/{{app_id}}/deploy"
  method: PUT
  status_code: 202
  validate_certs: no
  headers:
    Content-Type: 'application/json'
    Accept: 'application/json'
    AUTHTOKEN: "{{ server_session.token }}"
  body_format: json
  body:
    version: "{{ staging.json.version }}"
run_once: true
register: deploy
changed_when: deploy|succeeded
```

I first tried converting it to integer with "| int" but that didnt work. I then tried "| type_debug" and validated the variable is an integer.

But I still get this error. If I replace the variable with a raw integer it works just fine. Using verbose output it still appears the value is being passed as a string.

```
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "attributes": null,
        "backup": null,
        "body": {
            "version": "48"
        },
        "body_format": "json",
```

Any idea what Im missing here or how I can work around this? Im currently running Ansible 2.4.0 for this project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a really strange default behavior of Ansible. It renders every value as string regardless its original type. So you end up with `staging.json.version` being a string instead of a numeric type.

This behavior can be altered in recent Ansible releases using the [jina2_native](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-jinja2-native) flag  **globally**.

Comment: Bro, hat's off to you.

Answer (score 2):

The *uri* module can take a pre-formatted body in JSON format. Try:

```
- name: Deploy Staging Blueprint
  local_action:
    module: uri
    url: "https://{{ server_address }}/api/application/{{app_id}}/deploy"
    method: PUT
    status_code: 202
    validate_certs: no
    headers:
      Content-Type: 'application/json'
      Accept: 'application/json'
      AUTHTOKEN: "{{ server_session.token }}"
    body_format: json
    body: '{ "version": {{ staging.json.version }} }'
  run_once: true
  register: deploy
  changed_when: deploy|succeeded
```

Answer (score 1):

Example with

```yaml
test_int: 50
```

Try using the Jinja variable without quotes in the body parameter i.e.

```yaml
body: '{ "test": {{ test_int }} }'
```

It works for me in Ansible 2.9.13